# Creating function boundaries in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function with a few boundaries in R. My main barrier is writing a boundary with "two ends", where my variable "x" is lager than "first boundary" and smaller than "second boundary".

I get an error, and I believe it has to do with the syntax of boundaries.
Does anyone know how it should be written?

This is my attempt in R:

```
func_Q2 <- function(x)
    if (-1 <= x < 0)  {x + 1}  # first parameter   ,the " < 0" does not work
    if (0 <= x < 1) {-x + 1}   # seccond parameter ,the " < 1" does not work
    else {0}
```

*The function I am trying to write into R*:

[image: The function i am trying to write into R]

Comment: a < b < c is not possible in R, instead use a < b & b < c

Comment: You may be interested in `?data.table::between`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, `a < b < c` is not possible, you have to do `a < b & b < c`

```
func_Q2 <- function(x){
  if (-1 <= x & x < 0) {x + 1}
  if (0 <= x & x < 1) {-x + 1}
  else {0}
}
func_Q2(-2)
> 0
func_Q2(-0.5)
> 0
func_Q2(0.5)
> 0.5
```

Warning, your first `if` does nothing, it is never return. Maybe the second `if` is an `else if`

Comment: That is what my warning says

Comment: How come 'func_Q2(-0.5)' doesn't do anything? 
How would you fix it such that 

func_Q2(-0.5) == 0.5

Comment: Expected result for -0.5 is 0.5 not 0. You have to replace the second `if` by `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this captures your intentions:

```
func_Q2 <- function(x){
  if (x < -1 || x >= 1) {
    0
  } else {
    1 - abs(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: `pmax(0, 1 - abs(x))` is also equivalent

Comment: @IceCreamToucan or simply `max(0, 1 - abs(x))` not vectorized anyway.